# How to connect multiple forms in main single form Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have multiple individual forms in Oracle Forms 11g.

I want to connect all multiple individual forms in main single form.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: @nightfox79 how to connect multiple forms in a single form with forms builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invoke the CALL_FORM for this purpose of calling multiple forms from a single form

Refer the below link for its usage

[CALL_FORM Example in Oracle 11g](http://www.erpschools.com/forms/using-call_form-to-invoke-another-form-in-oracle-applications)

Answer (score 1):

Not simply.

I've done something similar to this before however, but it was over 10 years ago and I might not remember all the details. We had a single form which needed to show multiple stacked canvases, each built in a separate FMB, and then subclassed into the main FMB.

This way, different developers can maintain the various canvases independently, and I was tasked  with merging their changes into the main FMB, which was relatively straightforward due to the subclassing.

(The main form had an empty content canvas with some gnarly code that dynamically expanded/contracted its height depending on which canvases were shown, and showed the stacked canvases at the appropriate y positions so they were all visible. This may or may not be relevant to what you're trying to achieve, though.)